# Execute a command inside thread/timer only once but keep thread/timer running?

Tags: delphi

This is part of the code inside a thread (or it could be a timer, doesn't matter):

```
timenow := Now;
strtime := FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss', timenow);
if frmBackup.getmetime = strtime then
begin
  frmBackup.lawl.Position := frmBackup.lawl.Position + 10;
end;
```

Basically the progress bar is just a test to know how many times it has been executed. So far, I was not able to stop it from executing more than once. I need it to execute once (when getmetime = strtime) then continue the thread/timer without executing the code, only executing it again when the time comes.

Possible?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you're asking a lot of nearly-duplicate questions.

Comment: Indeed it seems, however, they're not. How can Alternative to Timer be a duplicate to RunOnlyOnce timer? You seem like a nice guy but quit busting my balls for no apparent reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put a boolean flag on frmBackup:

```
timenow := Now;
strtime := FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss', timenow);
if (frmBackup.getmetime = strtime) and (not frmBackup.RanOnce) then
begin
  frmBackup.lawl.Position := frmBackup.lawl.Position + 10;
  frmbackup.RanOnce := true;
end;
```

Also, be careful of trying to compare times with `=` like that.  If your timer fires one second later than the time you're aiming for, for whatever reason, your code will fail. It would be better to use >= or build some margin of error into the comparison. (And use direct TDateTime comparisons instead of string comparisons.)

And one other thing: if you actually are in another thread, (as opposed to a timer running on the same thread,) updating a VCL control will fail in strange ways, because the underlying Windows API stuff has a thread affinity to the main thread of your program.  If you're going to do it that way, look at `TThread.Synchronize` and `TThread.Queue` and use one or the other for your UI updates.